# Exam Question: Which of the following terms best describes Snowflake's database architecture?

Tags: database, architecture, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

some say "shared disk", others say "multi-cluster shared data". What's the correct answer?

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/intro-key-concepts.html#snowflake-architecture

Comment: Shital - is the question about the Snowflake SaaS solution, or, snowflake data architecture - where 'snowflake' is a variation of star-schema?  https://www.guru99.com/star-snowflake-data-warehousing.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not a "shared disk" architecture. It's architecture is a "multi-cluster shared data". Now, this is not a standard term and that's why the confusion.

"shared disk" architecture is not new but it has some limitations compared to "shared nothing" architecture which is more popular these days due to scalability and performance. Shared Nothing architecture has some other limitations like data inconsistency, multiple copies of data etc. As per Snowflake, to get the best of both worlds, it does not follow any of those but is based on architecture that is a hybrid of traditional shared-disk and shared-nothing database architectures.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/intro-key-concepts.html#snowflake-architecture